# Python inheritance or extra properties for faceting

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

First of all, I'm very very new to Python/Django but I've using other technologies for years.

In a website where users can create Publications (let's think of Amazon for example), I have a `Publication` object that contains the basic stuff, such as title, details, price, etc.

I want, however, to include certain properties that are particular to object type (cloth would have size, color, for men/for women; cars would have brand, model, engine, transmission, etc).  The idea is to use Haystack/Elasticsearch to do faceting on those properties, depending on what the user is searching for.

So, here's the basic model:

```
# main publication class
class Publication(models.Model):
    OBJECT_TYPE = (
        ('cloth', 'Cloth'),
        ('electronics', 'Electronics'),
        ('car', 'Cars'),
    )
    object_type = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                                    choices=OBJECT_TYPE,
                                    default='electronics')
    title = models.CharField()
    details = models.CharField()
    # other fields...

# Haystack index
class PublicationIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    object_type = indexes.CharField(faceted=True, model_attr='object_type')
    # other fields...
```

The question is, where should I store those other properties?

One option would be to have another class/model with the details and an FK to the publication. If so, how should I build the index then?  Another option would be to put all the properties for all the publications in the `Publication` model, that would be the simplest but probably not elegant.

Another option would be to do inheritance to have `CarPublication`, `ClothPublication`, etc. If so, the question would be, how do I handle the basic stuff to avoid duplicating all the screens one for each publication type.

I will have only 3 publication types and I don't think I'll be adding more, so doing the inheritance, for example, is a doable option (Amazon has hundreds of categories so it's different).

What would be the best approach?

FYI, using Python 3, Django 1.9, Haystack 2.5-dev, Elasticsearch.

Comment: [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) handles this beautifully

Comment: Thanks @IanPrice. Looks good. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) handles this beautifully.

From the docs:

```
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

class Project(PolymorphicModel):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ArtProject(Project):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ResearchProject(Project):
    supervisor = models.CharField(max_length=30)


>>> Project.objects.create(topic="Department Party")
>>> ArtProject.objects.create(topic="Painting with Tim", artist="T. Turner")
>>> ResearchProject.objects.create(topic="Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor="Dr. Winter")
# Get polymorphic query results:

>>> Project.objects.all()
[ <Project:         id 1, topic "Department Party">,
  <ArtProject:      id 2, topic "Painting with Tim", artist "T. Turner">,
  <ResearchProject: id 3, topic "Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor "Dr. Winter"> ]
```

Comment: I've marked yours as a solution because of the help, but I ended up doing what I explained in my answer. I've tried your and it worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Very nice. Just in case anyone is considering this in the future, django-polymorphic allows for filtering by model type as such - `Project.objects.instance_of(ArtProject)` >>> `[ <ArtProject:      id 2, topic "Painting with Tim", artist "T. Turner"> ]` (and you can also use `not_instance_of`)

Answer (score 1):

OK. Even when @IanPrice answer was really good and helpful, this is what I ended up doing abstract base classes ([see the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)):

```
class BasePublication(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    # base properties

class CarPublication(BasePublication):
    # car-specific properties

class ClothPublication(BasePublication):
    # cloth-specific properties
```

The reason are:

- In my case I don't need to query for both things at the same time. It is possible, but more complicated since they are stored in different tables.
- Performance, using inheritance adds an inner join or additional selects. It might not be important with the amount of information I have, but I'm crazy about performance, so I didn't like that.
- Simplicity, in my case using inheritance added more problems that what it solved, so using abstract classes was simpler.